# Include my custom.js in iOS Cordova Framework

Tags: javascript, ios, css, cordova

I am new to iOS Cordova development. Well I have managed to run the sample html.

But the problem I am facing is with the CSS and JS files. I cannot access the files using simple `<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> or in the case of javascript js/test.js`.

Can anyone please tell how I can get the files? Or it will be very helpful if you can provide some links to blogs or video tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about style but js should work if you added it to your `index.html` file. Try do a clean and then build again.

Comment: I did this `<script src="childbrowser.js"></script>` bellow `<script type="text/javascript" id="phonegap" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>` and it works just fine.

Comment: Alright it worked for me as well. But I am facing some other issues as well. I have jquery.js in my js folder. And no matter what I cannot load it into my html. Whereas a simple js file with `alert("hello");` is working. What am I missing can you tell me?

Comment: i dont know. maybe you could share your code and file structure